# Dynamically creating lambda functions

Tags: python, function, lambda

I am trying to dynamically create functions in the following way:

```
a = []
for i in range(2):
    a.append(lambda: i)
print(a[0](), a[1]())
```

The results surprised me at first: `1 1`.
My expectations were that `0 1` would be printed since the first function was created with `i = 0` and the second one with `i = 1`. Then I realized that `i` is a global variable, thus the result.
My questions are:

- Is there a way to create functions dynamically so that they would print `0 1`?
- Is there something I misinterpret in the code?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The simple, ugly trick, explained in the dupe, is `a.append(lambda i=i: i)`. There's also more verbose solutions.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes! It does the trick, so it'll do! Thanks a lot!